# Angular2 OnInit, not getting data from server

Tags: angular, constructor

I'm having problems getting data from server using NgOnInit function. With this data, I want to paint a plot using morris.js but i'm not getting that data.

I have a service that obtains all car reparations from DB and then I want to paint a daily plot of total reparations. I'm getting a void array of reparations and I can't paint anything.

My code:

```
constructor(_router: Router, public http: Http, private _reparacionsService: ReparacioService) {
    this.router = _router;
}

getReparacions() {
    this._reparacionsService.getReparacions().subscribe(rep => this.reparacions = rep.json());
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getReparacions();
    this.getLastWeek();
    this.getReparacionsDia();
    window['Morris'].Line({
        element: 'repDaychart',
        data: this.reparacionsDies,
        xkey: 'data',
        ykeys: ['totalReparacions'],
        labels: ['totalReparacions'],
        parseTime: false,
        xLabels: "day"
    });
}
```

I already imported and declared OnInit:

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
  export class DashBoard implements OnInit
```

I'm using angular beta 17.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code is async

```
this._reparacionsService.getReparacions().subscribe(rep => this.reparacions = rep.json());
```

this means that `this.getLastWeek();` in

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getReparacions();
    this.getLastWeek();
```

is executed before `this.reparacions = rep.json()` is executed

You probably want to do something like

```
getReparacions() {
    return this._reparacionsService.getReparacions().map(rep => this.reparacions = rep.json());
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getReparacions().subscribe(data => {
    this.getLastWeek();
    this.getReparacionsDia();
    window['Morris'].Line({
        element: 'repDaychart',
        data: this.reparacionsDies,
        xkey: 'data',
        ykeys: ['totalReparacions'],
        labels: ['totalReparacions'],
        parseTime: false,
        xLabels: "day"
    });
  });
}
```

This only works if not other calls (`getLastWeek()`, getReparacionsDia()`) are async as well.

Comment: I tried it but i'm getting an error:                                                                

TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined                                          Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at DashBoard.ngOnInit (dashboard.component.ts:36)
    at AppView._View_DashBoard_Host0.detectChangesInternal (DashBoard_Host.template.js:34)
    at AppView.detectChanges (angular2.dev.js:23638)
    at AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (angular2.dev.js:23657)
    at AppView._View_Home0.detectChangesInternal (Home.template.js:1338)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `return` in `getReparacions()`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Now doesn't give errors but It doesn't paint the plot. I will look for it.